# Ошибка при попытке разлогиниться в Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, logout

Вываливается ошибка "MethodNotAllowedHttpException", при попытке выйти из учетной записи. Использую авторизацию из коробки. Вот роуты:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('welcome');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function(){

    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){

    Route::get('logout', function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');

    Route::get('/account', 'User\AccountController@index')->name('account');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function(){
        Route::get('/adminpanel', 'Admin\AdminController@index')->name('admin');
    });

});
```

В LoginController

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->performLogout($request);
    return redirect()->route('welcome');
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было изменить в роутах

```
Route::get('logout', function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');
```

На

```
Route::post('logout', function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');
```